Framer Motion layout transition affects siblings in a weird way
I just started learning React and Framer Motion. But apparently with great power come great bugs.
So this following code is from my simple app where I just want to render cards with recipes.
The bug happens when I open 2nd or any subsequent card (lets call it SUB card), close it and then open any previous card, the heading {recipe.title} of subsequent card that was opened and closed (SUB) is "jumping on the spring" independently of the card background itself as previous card is being scaled.
Component RecipeTable.jsx:
export default function RecipeTable({ recipes }) {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <LayoutGroup>
                        {recipes.map((recipe, index) => (
                            <RecipeCard
                                recipe={recipe}
                                key={index}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </LayoutGroup>
                </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Component RecipeCard.jsx:
export default function RecipeCard({ recipe, key }) {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const controls = useAnimation();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpen) {
            controls.start({
                scale: [1, 1.2, 1,],
                rotate: [0, 270, 0],
                transition: { duration: 0.7 },
            });
        }
    }, [isOpen, controls]);

    return (
        <motion.div className="card-container">
            <motion.div
                transition={{ layout: { type: "spring", duration: 0.7 }}}
                layout
                onClick={() => ! isOpen && setIsOpen(true)}
                className="card"
                style={isOpen ? {} : {cursor: "pointer"}}
                whileHover={ isOpen ? {} : { scale: 1.05 }}
            >
                { isOpen && (
                    <motion.button
                        className="close-button"
                        onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                        initial={{scale: 1, rotate: 0}}
                        animate={controls}
                        whileHover={{scale: 1.3, rotate: 0}}
                    >
                        &times;
                    </motion.button>
                )}
                <motion.h2 layout={"position"}>
                    {recipe.title}
                </motion.h2>
                {isOpen && (
                    <motion.div
                        className="card-expand"
                        initial={{opacity: 0}}
                        animate={{opacity: 1}}
                        transition={{duration: 0.5}}
                    >
                        <p>{recipe.ingredients}</p>
                        <p>{recipe.instructions}</p>
                    </motion.div>
                )}
            </motion.div>
        </motion.div>
    )
}

styles my.css:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #ADA996;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #EAEAEA, #DBDBDB, #F2F2F2, #ADA996);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAEAEA, #DBDBDB, #F2F2F2, #ADA996); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.card-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3rem 5rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

.card p {
    line-height: 150%;
}

.close-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1rem;
    right: -1rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: black;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.card-expand {
    max-width: 60vw;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .card-expand {
        max-width: 100vw;
    }
}

I tried to set layout property to the outer <motion.div> which fixed it but kind of messed up the animation of other cards "making space" for the opening card.
EDIT:
Adding empty transition slightly helped but the title still "wiggles" inside the card and the transition when opening the card stops being smooth...
<motion.h2 layout={"position"} transition={{}}>
    {recipe.title}
</motion.h2>


Solved. So the problem was this thing:
whileHover={ isOpen ? {} : { scale: 1.05 }}

I dont understand how it is related to the problem. Probably a bug on Framer Motion side
